# How to set price to be £9.99 including VAT at 20%

Tags: vat

I notice that in the release notes for Magento 1.8.0 (http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce-18-later-release-notes) it says the following:-

"Specifying that prices display in the web store excluding tax and setting a 20% tax rate (or discount rate) now calculates the grand total correctly. It is now possible to have grand totals in amounts like 6.99, 9.99, or 99.99—regardless of the currency units used in the web store. "

But, it does not say how to achieve this?

I have a store where the prices are entered ex VAT. VAT is 20% - and this is then applied to the product price and the Including VAT price shown on the front end.

I wish to have a final including VAT price for a product being £9.99

But - if I enter 8.32 in the admin Price - it results in 9.98 on the front end. If I enter 8.33 it results in 10.00 on the front end.

How do I achieve the £9.99 price that the release notes say is now possible with a Tax rate of 20%?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Try filling in the price 8.325 since the price supports up to 4 decimal places.
In this case you should get the final price like this:

```
8.325 * (1 + 20/100) = 8.325 * 1.2 = 9.99
```

**Edit**
Apparently I was wrong. Sort of...
If you enter the price as  `8.325` it will be saved in the db as `8.325` and everything will work correctly. This part I got right.
But in the backend you will see the price as `8.33` and if you hit save again you will have it in the db as `8.33`. This is the part I was wrong about.
Everything happens because of the input renderer for the price attributes.  The `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Helper_Form_Price` class is used to render the price inputs.
At the end of the class there is this method:

```
public function getEscapedValue($index=null)
{
    $value = $this->getValue();

    if (!is_numeric($value)) {
        return null;
    }

    return number_format($value, 2, null, '');
}
```

This makes the prices show with only 2 decimals even if in the db there are 4 of them.
I guess you have to override this method and replace

```
`return number_format($value, 2, null, '');`
```

with

```
`return number_format($value, 4, null, '');`
```

Most probably this will solve your issue and let you fill in 4 decimal numbers without the fear of the value getting modified on the next save.

Comment: Really? Is there a setting for that? mine always rounds to 2dp.

Comment: On frontend the prices are shown by default with 2 decimals by default, but in the backend you should be able to fill in 4 decimals as far as I know...I will double check and let you know

Comment: damn it...you are right. I remember this working on older versions. I will dig deeper and come back with a working solution...hopefully.

Comment: @Richard. See my update. Maybe it helps.

Comment: Hah, you're good.

Comment: Thanks for the input people :) If possible I dont want to have to edit the code - as this was then causing issues sending 3 decimal places as an order total to the likes of Paypal etc so that was failing as a possible fraudulent transaction...
I am testing this on an out of the box 1.9 installation now and it does not let me enter in more than 2 decimal places in admin.....

Comment: @Marius - Any news on your deeper digging Marius? Really keen to see if Magento can handle 9.99 without modifying the code... Seems crazy if not..

Comment: @user3032942. See the update to my answer. it seams (to me at least) that this is a small bug. Like I said, you need to modify the block that renders the price fields to support 4 decimals and everything should work smoothly.

Comment: @Marius - Cheers, will give that a go and see if it causes the issue with fraudulent Paypal and Secure Trading alerts