# UK Catalog, Goods excluding VAT - rounding issues on front end display

Tags: magento2, tax, tax-rounding

On Magento2  (v2.0.7)

We are storing catalog values without tax. We want the front end display to show £9.99 inc tax - as the UK tax-inclusive product price.

I enter the prices ex-VAT in the backend, and have front-end display price+tax.

Question: What value do i have to enter to get a price of £9.99 (front end)?
Answer: £9.99/1.2 (VAT @ 20%) = £8.325

So i have to put £8.325 into the back end so that:

£8.325*1.2 = £9.99.

OK - so i do that......

But Magento only seems to store the price to 2DP. - so it stores

£8.33 (rounded up without me wanting it to)

so taking Magento's £8.33

£8.33*1.2 = £10.00 (displayed on front-end) <--- BUT I WANT 9.99!!

because to achieve a £9.99 inc VAT price you need to store £8.325 - 3DP, but Magento 2 doesn't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set price to be £9.99 including VAT at 20%](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42390/how-to-set-price-to-be-%c2%a39-99-including-vat-at-20) - Edit: This is magento2, my bad